# Asp.Net download file error when choosing 'Open' in IE9

Tags: c#, asp.net, internet-explorer, download

I am using Response to have my application open up a Word Document for the user.  If the user chooses to save the file, it saves it and the file looks how it should when you open it.  If the user chooses to open the file right away, they receive an error saying that IE couldn't open the file.  If they choose 'Retry', MS Word shows an error saying it cannot find the file.  Below are screen shots showing my situation.  Also, here is the code I have to display the file:

```
        this.Context.Response.Clear();
        this.Context.Response.ClearContent();
        this.Context.Response.ClearHeaders();
        this.Context.Response.BufferOutput = true;
        this.Context.Response.ContentType = "application/msword";
        this.Context.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Length", bytes.Length.ToString()); 
        this.Context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + "Test Document.doc");
        this.Context.Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
        this.Context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
```

Here is the screen when prompting the user of the download:
[image]

Here is the screen after user chooses 'Open'
[image]

Here is the screen after user chooses 'Retry'.  This screen is coming for MS Word.
[image]

****EDIT****
I have found a bit of code online that I tried testing and issue still occures when I call this function:

```
    protected void GenerateMsWordDoc()
    {
        string strBody = "<html>" +
            "<body>" + 
                "<div>Your name is: <b>Billy Bob</b></div>" +
                "<table width='100%' style='background-color:#cfcfcf;'><tr><td>1st Cell body data</td><td>2nd cell body data</td></tr></table>" +
                "Ms Word document generated successfully." +
            "</body>" +
            "</html>";
        string fileName = "MsWordSample.doc";
        // You can add whatever you want to add as the HTML and it will be generated as Ms Word docs
        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Type", "application/msword");
        Response.AppendHeader ("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename="+ fileName);
        Response.Write(strBody);
    }
```

Comment: What version of Word is in use?

Comment: Is Styles/Site.css a css of your site ?
if so, did you check client side the Response Header and Content to see if nothing is appended to the Response during EndRequest ?

Comment: I have this exact same issue, however I get it with PDF files and sometimes Excel files. However, usually it just works. Then at some point IE borks and after that it will not directly Save+Open the download for me. Retrying doesn't help. From that point on I have to Save first, wait for the download to finish, and Open it from the completed downloads window. Really weird issue.

Comment: Never really figured out what the issue was for this. I ended up creating a new project in Visual Studio and when I did this, everything seemed to work perfectly. I used the same settings and same web config, so I am not sure what the issue was.

Comment: I can't add an answer as this question has been closed, but we had a very similar issue on a recent deployment. The problem came from the fact that recent security changes requested by the client's IA had implemented a no-cache header for all content. This meant that the browser was deleting the file from temporary files before it could be opened. Use fiddler or some other packet inspector to look at the response header to make sure you don't have something similar. This KB article, http://support.microsoft.com/kb/323308, helped point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Can you post the sample data being used? I tried below code in IE9 works fine.

```
this.Context.Response.Clear();
this.Context.Response.ClearContent();
this.Context.Response.ClearHeaders();
this.Context.Response.BufferOutput = true;
this.Context.Response.ContentType = "application/msword";
this.Context.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Length", "12");
this.Context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + "Test Document.doc");
this.Context.Response.BinaryWrite(new byte[] { });
this.Context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
```

**Your recent code is also working fine. I am using IE9. Below are version details...**

[image]

Comment: The sample data is pretty large.  It is another word document that was saved as xml.

Comment: Can you test it with small data and in case issue persist, pls share the data.

Comment: I have tested it by opening MS Word 2007. Save a blank doc as .xml.  Then I read in that file and store the xml in a string.  Take that string, turn it into binary by doing:     Byte[] bytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(xml);   Then I send that bytes array to write to the Response.  Issue still occurs doing this.

Comment: See Edit above for a code example as well...

Comment: Still works fine at my end. Check version details my side.

Answer (score 1):

Spaces in the filename parameter of content-disposition have been known to cause errors across different browser versions. Try enclosing the filename in double quotes:

```
this.Context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + "Test Document.doc" + "\"");
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but this didn't solve my issue.